# MongoDB: $set specific fields for a document array elements only if not null

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, typeorm

I have a collection with the following documents (for example):

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61acefe999e03b9324czzzzz"
  },
  "matchId": {
    "$oid": "61a392cc54e3752cc71zzzzz"
  },
  "logs": [
    {
      "actionType": "CREATE",
      "data": {
        "talent": {
          "talentId": "qq",
          "talentVersion": "2.10",
          "firstName": "Joelle",
          "lastName": "Doe",
          "socialLinks": [
            {
              "type": "FACEBOOK",
              "url": "https://www.facebook.com"
            },
            {
              "type": "LINKEDIN",
              "url": "https://www.linkedin.com"
            }
          ],
          "webResults": [
            {
              "type": "VIDEO",
              "date": "2021-11-28T14:31:40.728Z",
              "link": "http://placeimg.com/640/480",
              "title": "Et necessitatibus",
              "platform": "Repellendus"
            }
          ]
        },
        "createdBy": "DEVELOPER"
      }
    },
    {
      "actionType": "UPDATE",
      "data": {
        "talent": {
          "firstName": "Joelle new",
          "webResults": [
            {
              "type": "VIDEO",
              "date": "2021-11-28T14:31:40.728Z",
              "link": "http://placeimg.com/640/480",
              "title": "Et necessitatibus",
              "platform": "Repellendus"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61acefe999e03b9324caaaaa"
  },
  "matchId": {
    "$oid": "61a392cc54e3752cc71zzzzz"
  },
  "logs": [....]
}
```

*a brief breakdown:* I have many objects like this one in the collection. they are a kind of an audit log for actions takes on other documents, 'Match(es)'. for example `CREATE` + the data, `UPDATE` + the data, etc.

As you can see, `logs` field of the document is an array of objects, each describing one of these actions.
`data` for each action **may or may not** contain specific fields, that in turn can also be an array of objects: `socialLinks` and `webResults`.

I'm trying to remove sensitive data from **all** of these documents with specified Match ids.
For each document, I want to go over the `logs` array field, and change the value of specific fields **only if they exist**, for example: change `firstName` to `*****`, same for `lastName`, if those appear. also, go over the `socialLinks` array if exists, and for each element inside it, if a field `url` exists, change it to `*****` as well.

What I've tried so far are many minor variations for this query:

```
      $set: {
        'logs.$[].data.talent.socialLinks.$[].url': '*****',
        'logs.$[].data.talent.webResults.$[].link': '*****',
        'logs.$[].data.talent.webResults.$[].title': '*****',
        'logs.$[].data.talent.firstName': '*****',
        'logs.$[].data.talent.lastName': '*****',
      },
```

and some play around with this kind of aggregation query:

```
[{
      $set: {
        'talent.socialLinks.$[el].url': {
          $cond: [{ $ne: ['el.url', null] },'*****', undefined],
        },
      },
    }]
```

resulting in errors like:  `message: "The path 'logs.0.data.talent.socialLinks' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates.",`

But I just cant get it to work... :(

Would love an explanation on how to exactly achieve this kind of set-only-if-exists behaviour.
A working example would also be much appreciated, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would suggest using [`$\[<indentifier>\]` (filtered positional operator)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) and [`arrayFilters`](https://database.guide/how-the-arrayfilters-parameter-works-in-mongodb/) to update the nested document(s) in the array field.

In `arrayFilters`, with `$exists` to check the existence of the certain document which matches the condition and to be updated.

```
db.collection.update({},
{
  $set: {
    "logs.$[a].data.talent.socialLinks.$[].url": "*****",
    "logs.$[b].data.talent.webResults.$[].link": "*****",
    "logs.$[b].data.talent.webResults.$[].title": "*****",
    "logs.$[c].data.talent.firstName": "*****",
    "logs.$[d].data.talent.lastName": "*****",
    
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "a.data.talent.socialLinks": {
        $exists: true
      }
    },
    {
      "b.data.talent.webResults": {
        $exists: true
      }
    },
    {
      "c.data.talent.firstName": {
        $exists: true
      }
    },
    {
      "d.data.talent.lastName": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WaDK673HX-7)

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and correct answer. a follow up question for the 'regular' non array document: how should my $set look if I want to update each element of an array field, only if that field exists. example document: `{ talent: {firstName: 'ab', socialLinks: [{a:1, url:2},{a:2, url:22}]}}`. If I try: `$set: {talent.webResults.$[].link: *****}` I get an error: `MongoError: The path 'talent.webResults' must exist in the document in order to apply array updates.`

Comment: Hi, I think this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CnNT8I7j8SA) may meet your requirement. You need filter all the documents that is with `"talent.webResults": { $exists: true }`.

Comment: Hmmm, do you want in same query as the answer or separate query? And the sample document is same as the question?

Comment: Wouldn't that mean only a sub-set of the documents, only the ones where that field exists? I'm actually looking to select multiple documents based on ID, and then for each document, if it has a `webResults` array field, iterate over the array elements and start-out some data, as well as go over 'regular' fields I know exist, like `first/lastName` and star them our as well.. ----- this would be a different query on a different collection, without the infamous `logs` array field.

Comment: some example data here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Bc_iQdBFekU

Comment: No, based on your latest document, you have to filter documents with `"talent.webResults": { $exists: true }` to prevent the `talent.webResults` not exist error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241568/discussion-between-maoration-and-yong-shun).